# Reusing app engine preloaded modules in my app

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm wondering if `appcfg.py` in GAE can be smart enough to not upload Python modules that actually should be pre-installed for GAE apps.

E.g., in my workflow I'm developing a pure Django app in standard Django environment which is not aware about `httplib2` module. For the project to be self-contained I'm using `virtualenv` and `pip install` missing modules. And since I couldn't make GAE's `appcfg.py` happy in `virtualenv` sandbox I simply created symlinks to all custom `virtualenv` modules in the root folder. So, for example, I ended up with a symlink `httplib2 --> ../src/lib/site-packages/httplib2`.

Then to check if `httpblib2` had actually been uploaded to GAE I used `appcfg.py download_app` command and, bingo, `httpblib2` was sitting there, eating my quota for no reason.

I could think of tweaking syspath etc. but it is interesting to know if there are some cleaner solutions...

Comment: The cleaner solution is to figure out why your virtualenv isn't working rather than trying to include them in the app directory.

Comment: yet still I have to put _some_ links in the app directory, e.g., `django-nonrel`. or, is there another way to tell GAE to upload additional modules?